# Sinatra heroku database access

Tags: ruby, heroku, console, sinatra

I have a sinatra ruby app in heroku. I am trying to access the database via the console.When I run the `heroku run console` , I am getting the following error.

```
Running console attached to terminal... up, run.10
    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:281:in `require':LoadError: no such file to load -- ./console.
```

When I try to access the record  using the following command, I am getting the following error :

```
irb(main):001:0> Setting.first
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Setting
    from (irb):1
    from bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me in what needs to be done. Am I missing some file or Is there a different way to access the tables in heroku?

Comment: In what stack are you?
You can chek with `heroku stack`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `heroku console` thing is an old hack for rails apps, but it won't work elsewhere. As you can see from the output, it's trying to load a file called `./console`. So, create a `console` file on your project root, and invoke IRB from it after having connected to your database. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby                                                                                                

require 'irb'                                                                                                      
require 'irb/completion'                                                                                           

require 'rubygems'                                                                                                 
require 'bundler/setup'                                                                                            

# require something that connects to your database
# or just connect here using ENV['DATABASE_URL']
require 'your_project_setup'

IRB.start
```